# Search by all properties of all arbitrarily nested subobjects in Elasticsearch document

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-aggregation

Is there any way to filter documents by any property name in unstructured data that may contain arbitrarily nested objects and arrays of objects in ElasticSearch?

For example, if I have the mapping:

```
GET my_index/_mapping/my_doc
{
    "my_index": {
        "mappings": {
            "my_doc": {
                "properties": {
                    "my_dynamic_object": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "dynamic": "false"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How could I search the string `"Foo"` inside of `"my_unknown_object"` using Elasticsearch query DSL or otherwise some other method?

As the last resort, I consider just manually fetching and scanning the entire index by the means of the programming language I use.

Comment: is my_dynamic_object - nested ?

Comment: @Nirmal, yes, my_dynamic_object has arbitrary structure, it may contain a number of objects that may, in turn, have nested objects and arrays of objects inside themselves